# Mule random error - unable to bind property

Tags: mule

I get this error randomly in the expression. Not able to find the root cause.

Here payload.SupplierId is always null. I'm setting it with a flowvariable field value.

Exception stack is:

```
1. object is not an instance of declaring class (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl:-2 (null)
2. unable to bind property (java.lang.RuntimeException)
    org.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.nodes.SetterAccessor:43 (null)
3. Execution of the expression "payload.SupplierId = flowVars.SupplierRequestData.SupplierId" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException)
    org.mule.el.mvel.MVELExpressionLanguage:213 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/expression/ExpressionRuntimeException.html)
4. Execution of the expression "payload.SupplierId = flowVars.SupplierRequestData.SupplierId" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException). Message payload is of type: SupplierResponse (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
    org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor:35 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)
```

Comment: SupplierRequestData is a POJO. I'm wondering if this is right way to access a field inside a flow variable?

Comment: or it should be flowVars['SupplierRequestData'].SupplierId

Comment: How can you expect solution without sharing your code ? Pls Share you code so it will be easy to detect the issue